# Custom setting behaviour in getValues

Tags: apex, customsetting

i report this issue happened to me while handling with custom setting. CSV__c is a custom setting, where are stored the configurations of some CSV files that the system has to process. The custom setting is of the type List.

```
string s = null; 
CSV__c c = CSV__c.getValues(s);
system.debug('@@@@@@@@'+ c);
```

I supposed that this will return null, while the custom setting method getValues return a record. Do you have any reference on this behaviour? 
Is not a big issue, i can make a change and check the parameter s, but i didn't found any reference to this behaviour. So I'm reporting this as knowledge and share this strange behaviour.

Furthermore, if i test

```
CSV__c c = CSV__c.getValues(**null**);
system.debug('@@@@@@@@'+ c);
```

the salesforce compiler is actually throwing an error.

Comment: Well, if you include `*` characters, it's not valid `Apex`. Any time you have an error, you should include its text on here. Just telling us there is an error is not helpful. Do you see the same behavior with `getInstance`?

Comment: ah sorry, error mine, ** was to put bold the text, i cant change the question, anyone can fix? Actually the same behaviour happens also with the getInstance.

Comment: Yeah, you cannot bold code, except for inline snippets using the **`\``** character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000eauWQAQ). It should eventually be fixed. It applies to both getValues and getInstance.